# Jsoup get element in value=" "

Tags: java, android, regex, string, jsoup

I want to find the element "buddyname" and get the element of value= "" in a HTML file which i put into a StringBuffer, in this case 5342test.
The element in value= "" can change so i can not search directly for 5342test.

```
<fieldset style="display:none"><input type="hidden" name="buddyname" value="5342test"/></fieldset>
```

How can i do this with jsoup? or is there an easier way, I already tried Pattern/Matcher but that did not work out as i had issues with the `Pattern.compile("<input[^>]*?value\\s*?=\\s*?\\\"(.*?)\\\")");`

Below some example code.
Thank you in advance.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(page); // page is a StringBuffer
        Elements td = doc.select("fieldset"); 

        for (Element td : tds) { 
          String tdText = td.text();
          System.out.println(tdText);
        }
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just use the attribute selector `[attrname=attrvalue]`.

```
Element buddynameInput = document.select("input[name=buddyname]").first();
String buddyname = buddynameInput.attr("value");
// ...
```

[Do not use regex to parse HTML](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html). It makes no sense if you already have a world class HTML parser at your hands.

#### See also:

- [Jsoup CSS selector syntax cookbook](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)
- [Jsoup `Selector` API documentation](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html)

Comment: Hi BalusC,
Thank you for the answer.
I just heard that jsoup has troubles with hidden fields, can you confirm this?
Thx

Comment: Never heard of this. Perhaps you're confusing with fields generated/manipulated by JavaScript. Jsoup doesn't parse JavaScript. It's just a HTML parser, not a web browser.